# Is there a safe way to refer to linker-only symbols that without taking the address of void expressions?

Tags: c, gcc, void-pointers, linker-scripts

A file has a series of void declarations used as `void*` as follows:

```
extern void __flash_rwdata_start;
...
initialize(&__flash_rwdata_start,
           ...
```

which are provided solely by the linker script as symbols referring to binary partitioning as follows (ie a pointer):

```
PROVIDE (__flash_rwdata_start = LOADADDR(.rwdata));
```

And this generates the following warning:

```
file.c:84:19: warning: taking address of expression of type 'void' [enabled by default]
```

As per the answer to [Why has GCC started warning on taking the address of a void expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263344/why-has-gcc-started-warning-on-taking-the-address-of-a-void-expression), I've changed this as follows (the function which takes the pointers uses an `unsigned long*` anyway):

```
extern unsigned long __flash_rwdata_start;
```

Now it occurs to me that the original definition had an implication of zero (or undefined) size, whereas the current definition does not, and unlike the answer to [Why has GCC started warning on taking the address of a void expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263344/why-has-gcc-started-warning-on-taking-the-address-of-a-void-expression) there is no "real underlying data type" that makes any logical sense.

Essentially I've defined a pointer that is valid, but does not point to a valid value, and thus it would be invalid to dereference.

Is there a safer or preferable way to avoid the warning, but without the idea of space being allocated, that can't be dereferenced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea that comes to mind is to make the object's type be an incomplete struct, like:

```
extern struct never_defined __flash_rwdata_start;
```

This way the address will be valid, but, as long as the type is never defined, not dereferenceable.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, the usual way besides "void" (which doesn't conform to C11 at least), is

`extern char __flash_rwdata_start[];`

I do like Tom's answer better though.