# Correctly create a global given only size and alignment

Tags: c

I have a type defined in one file. It's complicated and messy to export from that file. I want to allocate it somewhere else. Roughly the pimpl idiom from C++, rendered in C.

I know its size. Thus I can malloc(size) and the magic rules around C lifetime mean the void pointer can be used as an instance of that type. However I don't want it on the heap.

In C++, one can use aligned storage and placement new. In C, there is no placement new. As far as I can tell there is no way to start a lifetime in some arbitrary memory in C.

Thus I have just written this dubious construct:

```
extern void thing;
__asm__("\t.type thing,@object\n"
        ".pushsection .data\n"
        "\t.global thing\n"
        "\t.p2align 3\n"
        "thing:\n"
        "\t.zero 4032\n"
        "\t.size thing, 4032\n"
        ".popsection\n"
        );
```

I am not totally confident what `extern void thing` means as far as C in concerned. In particular,  I can't write that in a header later and define a specific type with the same name in source - the compiler rejects the combination. See also [Why does gcc allow extern declarations of type void (non-pointer)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038964/why-does-gcc-allow-extern-declarations-of-type-void-non-pointer)

Can one do better than this? I don't care about the ergonomics, only whether the type aliasing rule of C will be able to uncover the subterfuge and burn things to the ground in a future compiler revision.

The proper thing to do as far as the language is concerned is abandon encapsulation and move the type with all its internal mess into a header, but I don't want to do that. I like the encapsulation.

Comment: How exactly is this type used?  Is it a `struct`?  If so, does some .c file have access to the implementation?

Comment: Also, why do you want to define an instance of this struct in a file besides the one that knows the implementation, and why is using the heap bad?

Comment: Most instances of the struct are in test code which I'd like to keep isolated from one another, one or two are in the application. Usually heap is dubious on performance grounds, though in this case I also don't have a libc.

Question is applicable to implementing interfaces like pthread's opaque type one so hopefully not too niche.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an array of the desired size:

```
#include <stddef.h>

char _Alignas(max_align_t) Raw[N];
```

C 2018 6.5 7 says a permissible type for aliasing is:

> … an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members…

And therefore you can access it using:

```
union U
{
    struct MyStruct S;
    char _Alignas(max_align_t) Raw[N];
};
```

For example:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   8

char _Alignas(max_align_t) Raw[N];

extern void foo(void *p);


int main(void)
{
    foo(Raw);
}


struct MyStruct
{
    int i;
    float f;
};

union U
{
    struct MyStruct S;
    char _Alignas(max_align_t) Raw[N];
};


void foo(void *p)
{
    union U *Up = p;
    Up->S.i = 3;
    Up->S.f = 4.5;
    printf("%d %g\n", Up->S.i, Up->S.f);
}
```

You can also define your type as an anonymous structure inside the union, making it look more like a direct structure:

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        int i;
        float f;
    };
    char _Alignas(max_align_t) Raw[N];
} MyType;


void foo(void *p)
{
    MyType *t = p;
    t->i = 3;
    t->f = 4.5;
    printf("%d %g\n", t->i, t->f);
}
```

Comment: That is interesting. The reasoning is that address of the two fields in the union must be equal, and all uses are of the struct field. Nothing starts the lifetime of the struct member, but iirc C has more permissive ideas about unions than C++ so there's a credible chance this is well formed.

Comment: extern union thing; followed by a definition of that union as an aligned char [] and the struct of interest is better than extern void. I think that puts it firmly in the category of C cannot miscompile it. Replacing the asm for the char would be excellent if valid, currently trying to make sense of that.

Comment: I don't think this holds. For example, if the char [] was not aligned or undersized, you could still aim a union pointer at it based on 6.5.7, but that would not work. Accessing the char through a union* is fine, but I believe accessing the non-existent real struct through that union is not. Disappointingly.

Comment: @JonChesterfield: 6.5 7 (not 6.5.7) is just the aliasing rule. It tells you whether the type of the lvalue used to access an object is acceptable. It says nothing about alignment or the amount of space. Those come from other parts of the C standard. Concluding that, because accessing misaligned memory or unsufficient memory would not work, that 6.5 7 is not applicable is a mistake. 6.5 7 does its role, which is to specify which types are acceptable for aliasing.

Comment: … For the behavior of some piece of C code to be defined, multiple criteria must be met. It must conform to the C grammar. The identifiers it uses must be declared. The types of the lvalues it uses must satisfy 6.5 7. The address must be sufficiently aligned. These are generally separate criteria. To make the behavior of the code defined, you make it conform to all the requirements: The aliasing rule must be satisfied. The alignment must be correct. The space must be sufficient.

Comment: That's persuasive. The union pointer for type is necessary but not sufficient. It's also consistent with how gcc and clang seem to be behaving, so this looks good to me. Thank you. Nice to have less inline asm.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a global `char` array and use `alignas` to specify the alignment:

```
#define THING_SIZE 4032
#define THING_ALIGN 4

alignas(THING_ALIGN) unsigned char thing[THING_SIZE];
```

This can still run afoul of strict aliasing requirements, but if you compile with strict aliasing disabled, i.e. `-fno-strict-aliasing` in gcc, it should work.

Alternately, you're allowed to create an `extern` declaration of an undefined struct provided you don't attempt to access its members.

For example:

implementation.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct thing {
    int a;
}

struct thing thing1 = { 5 };

void foo(struct thing *p)
{
    printf("%d\n", p->a);
}
```

main.c:

```
struct thing;

extern struct thing thing1;

void foo(struct thing *);

int main()
{
    foo(&thing1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: extern struct definitely works, that's what I'm using at present. It avoids leaking the struct details (win) but means I need to put the global in the library code, not the caller(s). fno-strict-aliasing trivialises the problem but I'm reluctant to require it

Comment: @JonChesterfield Do you need more than one instance of it?  If so, what's wrong with dynamic allocation?